# Using SpEL (or any expression language) in Quarkus for object transformation

Tags: quarkus

I am trying to find out how to use SpEL (or any other expression language) in my Quarkus applications to handle basic object transformation via injected configuration (and run on Graal).

I am not sure if/what is possible here and I cant find much in the way of docs or how-tos.

I see that this can be possibly be used via the Apache Camel extension, but right now that would be overkill for this requirement.

Any pointers or guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Not much - I cant find docs, examples or howtos for this anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported in core Quarkus